# SysTick handler multiple definitions

Tags: arm, cortex-m

Looking at Blinky example (Keil MDK5 installation) particularly for ST32F769, I noticed SysTick_Handler twice, apart from third- weak definition in startup assembler file. First one in irq_cm4f.s:

```
SysTick_Handler PROC
            EXPORT   SysTick_Handler
            IMPORT   osRtxTick_Handler
            PUSH     {R0,LR}                ; Save EXC_RETURN
            BL       osRtxTick_Handler      ; Call osRtxTick_Handler
            POP      {R0,LR}                ; Restore EXC_RETURN
            MRS      R12,PSP
            B        SVC_Context
```

and another in EventRecorder.c:

```
void SysTick_Handler (void) {
  SysTickOverflowCounter++;
  SysTickOverflowUpdated = 1U;
}
```

What confuses me is how it happens that two procedures "override" the weak one (mentioned above) ?

Comment: Is it possible that the C `SysTick_Handler` is renamed to `osRtxTick_Handler` via some `#define SysTick_Handler osRtxTick_Handler`?

Comment: Get the linker to tell you which it's using, usually that will be in a map file if you ask Keil to generate one.

Comment: Due to #defines it uses assembler one, but there exists #define variant when both seems to be active.  
@Erlkoenig - good idea but no such or similar line in project

Comment: the disassembly shows both?

Comment: I think I found where ambiguity is. When I change (mentioned) #define EVENT_TIMESTAMP_SOURCE from 0 (which is now) to 1 then compiler complains of multiple definitions of SysTick_Handler.